# Biblatex: style, citestyle and fullcite cause error in etoolbox

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing, multiple-citations

I am using beamer and biblatex together.
In the preamble, I have separate cite and citestyle:

```
\documentclass[professionalfont,hyperref=unicode,xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=biber,%
            style=authoryear,%
            citestyle=apa,%
            block=par,%
            citetracker=true,%
            autocite=superscript,%
            sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{lily}
```

When I use `\cite{}` or `\parencite{}` command, the presentation is rendered with no error.

When I use `\fullcite{}`, the presentation is still rendered successfully, but with error:

```
Package etoolbox Error: Boolean '\ifbbx:in' undefined.
```

May I ask what does this error means and how to fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea to use only citestyle apa. apa is quite complex and you should use it either completly or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`style=apa,` from the `biblatex-apa` bundle is a specialised style that tries to implement the citation and bibliography style from the *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association* as closely as possible in `biblatex`.

As such the style is only intended to be used to replicate APA style and is implicitly expects that it is not mixed with another style.

This means that `style=authoryear, citestyle=apa,` might not work as expected. In any case this combination will definitely not produce proper APA style.

If you need APA style, you must load only `apa`

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=apa,
            block=par,]{biblatex}
```

If you don't need APA style, it is better not to use `biblatex-apa` at all and go for a standard style

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,%
            style=authoryear,%
            block=par,%
            citetracker=true,%
            autocite=superscript,%
            ]{biblatex}
```